# quoting a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a bit of code on the web that I would like to use.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fbreplace").html.replace(/<!-- FBML /g, "");
$(".fbreplace").html.replace(/ -->/g, "");
$(".fbreplace").style.display = "block";
});
```

The problem is the browser thinks

```
<!--
```

is a real comment. How would I quote it in a way to tell the browser look for that string and it is not a real comment?

Comment: [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is a method and not a property.

Comment: You can combine the two regexes together as `/<!-\- FBML | -\->/g`.

Comment: Which browser is this and which version of the browser?

Answer (score 6):

Escaping one of the symbols won't change the regular expression. You can use a backslash to prevent the browser from interpreting the `--` as the start or end of an HTML comment:

```
/<!-\- FBML /g
```

Having said that, I don't know of any modern browser that would misinterpret a piece of Javascript as a comment if the Javascript is correctly enclosed in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: You should better split `<!` as that’s already a [token in SGML](http://www.is-thought.co.uk/book/sgml-4.htm#Fig4-4) (markup declaration open).

Comment: @Gumbo: Perhaps both... the Javascript code could already be inside an HTML comment.

Comment: Then the same should be applied to `--` in the closing `-->`.

Comment: And `<!` is not a the “start of a comment declaration” but a *markup declaration open*. It’s also used in a doctype declaration (`<!DOCTYPE … >`), a CDATA declaration (`<!CDATA[ … ]]>`), an element declaration (`<!ELEMENT … >`), an attribute list declaration (`<!ATTLIST … >`), an entity declaration (`<!ENTITY … >`), etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're after overall:

```
$(function() {
  $(".fbreplace").html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/<!-\- FBML | -->/g, "");
  }).show();
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Rzqdk/), `.html` isn't a property of a jQuery object you can modify, you can however pass a function to [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and perform the `.replace()` on each occurrence.

Comment: @nick-craver. It works in jquery 1.4.2 but I have 1.3.2 on my server. Anyway to get it to work for 1.3.2?

Comment: @nick-craver - thank you so much. Now I just need to figure out how to replace the xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" in the html tag so my page will validate!

Comment: @keith - If you do a replace it's still not valid, the initial markup's still coming down, you can add a `.replace()` for that string if you must...but I don't think it'll help the validation piece any.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of escaping the regex as the other answers suggest, I would just put the code in an external file if I were you. That way it could also be cached, making it a little bit more efficient, and there would be more separation between behavior (scripts) and structure (markup), making your project more manageable.